# A basic question on real analysis (limit)

Tags: real-analysis

What is the value of the expression $$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\lambda t}\rfloor} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda ^k}{k!}$$ Will it depend on $t$? $t$ just controls the number of terms which is infinity as $\lambda\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is $P(S_\lambda\leqslant\lambda t)$, where the distribution of the random variable $S_\lambda$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$. By the (weak) law of large numbers, the limit when $\lambda\to\infty$ is $0$ if $t\lt1$ and $1$ if $t\gt1$. By the central limit theorem, it is $\frac12$ if $t=1$.